# Error while calling webservice. NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: ios, nserror

I am developing an App. While calling one of my web services i got Error,

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7f9200696fc0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

Here is my Code:-

```
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSURL *post=[NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:post cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:50];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *body=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@",userId];

[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (data==nil) {
    return;
}


NSLog(@"data from JSON =%@",data);
```

When i printed my NSData then i Got some Error in parse,

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in <b>/var/www
```

Now, what can I do to solve this problem? Can any one suggest?

Comment: NSLog `response`, `error` and add them to the question.

Comment: I always wonder why developers do this: `allowLossyConversion:YES`. Is a loss of data really a good idea? `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is no longer a good idea, it is usually better to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, that will allow other languages and even <shudder> emoji.

Comment: Thanx for correcting me. I am very new to iOS to I am not familiar with most of the methods, but now i'll read about those methods .

Comment: I already gave NSLog error in first line 

     Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7f9200696fc0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: You did not provide the response, among the response data is the http status code.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I was getting error because of server response. Now it is solved and thnxx for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the http status code is important, the server can return a server specific response code.

See  [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Note that server many tines define application specific 5xx error codes.

Comment: do you have any contact information publicly available?